# UWP Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.1 API not found

Tags: c#, uwp, compiler-errors

I was trying to run one of my apps after a fresh windows installation, and then I get this message in Visual Studio:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF3] Windows cannot install package 464|APPPUBLISHER|.|APPNAME|_1.7.0.0_x86__yejd587sfa94t because this package depends on a framework that could not be found. Provide the framework "Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.1" published by "CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US", with neutral or x86 processor architecture and minimum version 2.11904.5004.0, along with this package to install. The frameworks with name "Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.1" currently installed are: {} |APPNAME|

And here is a screenshot (The app name and publisher are hidden):

[image: This is what it shows up]

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Also, in a desperate case, if I publish a recreation of this app in the Microsoft Store, will it install properly?

Edit: it seems like every time I change the version of the app, the package that won't install synchronizes with the changes

Edit 2: Is there any way to download this package from NuGet or restore it to the app package?

Edit 3: This app was always a big problem and never behaved as it should. This isn't the first time I'm having similar problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem and, actually, the only solution. Since this app had a history of API problems, I decided to make a new one with the exact same properties, but with some fresh NuGet packages. This solved the issue and improved the performance a lot. Now, I don't have to worry about it failing to load every time I reinstall Windows since it was the only app that caused problems.

The package that this app was asking for was a cache that I couldn't get rid of, and was stuck in the files as a dependency on something that doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to right click on references, Select Manage NuGet Packages and searched for that package?

[image]